# Shelly 1 Configuration

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, i2c, electron, configuration

I am trying to implement the Shelly 1 switch for an electronic device I have. The electronic device has an open collector output channel (AUX1). It also has two output pins Z8 and C.

When Z8 and C are shorted, the electronic device performs an action. Status of this action is provided via the open collector output channel AUX1. Z8 and C are current limited.

The device also has a 12V supply output (rated to 500mA).

I've attached the schematic for your reference.

Basically I want it to do the following with the Shelly 1:

1. Short out Z8 and C on the controller via MQTT.
2. Provide an alert via MQTT when the AUX1 changes state.

Can you control these events individually via an MQTT broker?

The Shelly needs to operate at 12 VDC. So I'm guessing the SW terminal will have 12 V present on it when powered up and is looking for a conductive path to ground. Have I got this right? Is this SW output current limited?

If so, this will be provided when AUX1 changes state.

[image: My schematic]

Manuals: https://shelly.cloud/products/shelly-1-smart-home-automation-relay/, https://www.miotechnic.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/Ness-D8X-D16X-User-Manual.pdf

Comment: Do you have the manuals for these devices? And what is MQTT?

Comment: @Finbarr MQTT is Message Queuing Telemetry Transport. It is a common protocol for IoT devices that send simple messages over the internet.

Comment: In the future please [edit] your question with new information rather than replying in comments.